# Retaining ObjectiveC Block Pointer in C++ Class

Tags: c++, objective-c

I'm passing an ObjectveC block pointer (in a wrapper class) into the constructor of a C++ class. I want to use it later on for status callbacks back to the wrapper.

e.g.

```
MyClass::MyClass(void (^statusUpdateCallback)(MyState*)) {
...
```

I'm storing it in a class variable as follows:

```
private:
    __strong void (^callback)(MyState*);
```

The problem is that by the time I come to call it, the block pointer has (probably) been deallocated and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

How can I make a copy of the block pointer and retain it or otherwise stop it going away?

Comment: This should not happen. ARC retains the block. Does your class have a non-trivial move constructor by any chance?

Comment: No I don't. My understanding (maybe wrong) is that the block pointer is created on the stack so it's deallocated when the constructor returns - unless I can increase its ref count.

Comment: I assumed you did `this->callback = statusUpdateCallback `, which implicitly increments the refcount through ARC. You're using ARC, right?

Comment: Yes I did and yes I am. I've created a workaround by assigning the block to a property in my wrapper class and passing that property into the constructor. Seems to work.